# Web API Cookies and Session Storage

Tags: c#, session, cookies, asp.net-web-api, owin

We have a Web API secured by cookies issued by the OWIN Cookie Authentication Middleware.

Apart from the generic authentication fields generated by the Cookie Auth Middleware, the cookies also store custom fields such as user id, name, ...

In a scenario of multiple instances of the Web API being deployed behind a Load Balancer, do we need to persist the sessions in SQL/Redis/...?

Thank you.

Comment: No, cookie authentication works based on cookie which store on client side, not in the session. So you don't need to do anything for load balancing

Comment: And the server doesn't need to store anything related to the cookies/sessions? I was trying to find a reference from Microsoft but can't find one. Can you point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Cookie is sent on every HTTP request from client to server, so you don't need to store on server side. I am not sure I can find a decent one for you, but you can search around to get more understanding first.

Comment: That was also my understanding but I remember reading somewhere that session storage was still used to store cookie references. Thanks!

Comment: Session ID is stored in cookie :), but not vice versa

Comment: Thanks! Cuong Le! If you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it. It would be great if we had an external reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So picking up on what Cuong Le said and looking at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies's [source code](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs) one can see that by default no storage is needed on the server side.

Storage is only required when the property IAuthenticationSessionStore is set. Source code comments say the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An optional container in which to store the identity across requests. When used, only a session identifier is sent
    /// to the client. This can be used to mitigate potential problems with very large identities.
    /// </summary>
    public IAuthenticationSessionStore SessionStore { get; set; }
```

I hope this helps!